# Can't generate pdf using php

Tags: php, jquery, fpdf

I am trying to generate the pdf using Fpdf using php but it's giving me the following error

> This page isn’t working
>   localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

i tried everything but it's not working. Here i just tried sample code for generating pdf.

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output("myPdfFile.pdf", "D");
?>
```

Comment: Error is due to path issue require('fpdf.php'); check for correct included file php and check

Comment: Check your server log to see what caused the 500 error. Quick guess is that `fpdf.php` is not in your include path and can't be found. Also make sure to turn on all error reporting so you will see any errors that might be happening. `ini_set('display_errors','1');ini_set('display_startup_errors','1');error_reporting(E_ALL);mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: May be issue of access level so give the permission : 
`sudo chmod -R 777 /"your files location"`

Answer (score -1):

I have had good success with the mPDF library.

https://mpdf.github.io/

Here are instructions on installation and usage.

https://mpdf.github.io/installation-setup/installation-v7-x.html

Comment: This does not answer the question. It simply suggests that the asker use a completely different package.